# Translate English to Corpus

Tags: code-golf, text-processing

The [Corpus](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Corpus) are a fictional faction from the popular video game [Warframe](https://www.warframe.com/) who have a somewhat interesting language.

Whilst other factions in the game such as the Grineer have some logic behind their language, the Corpus is simply a lossy substitution of the English language.

All Corpus words are the same as their English counterparts, except with the following alphabetical mappings:

[image: English to Corpus mapping]

This causes some problems with pronunciation as:

`yes` becomes `yey`
`say` becomes `yay`
`yay` becomes `yay`
`sassy` becomes `yayyy`
`case` becomes `yaye`

Here's a text version of the mappings:

```
a -> a
b -> t
c -> y
d -> p
e -> e
f -> t
g -> j
h -> k
i -> i
j -> t
k -> k
l -> p
m -> s
n -> t
o -> o
p -> k
q -> r
r -> t
s -> y
t -> p
u -> u
v -> t
w -> j
x -> k
y -> y
z -> b
```

## The challenge

Given text using the English alphabet, output its Corpus translation.

For example, the text `Hello, World!` becomes `Keppo, Jotpp!` in Corpus

#### The Rules

- Input will only consist of ASCII printable characters
- Input text may contain whitespace and punctuation, these must be preserved
- Capitalization of letters must be preserved
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so naturally, fewest bytes wins!

### The Testcases

Test cases are separated with `<===========>`, with a blank line between input and expected output

```
Hello, World!

Keppo, Jotpp!
<===========>
Yes

Yey
<===========>
TestcaSe

PeypyaYe
<===========>
Programming Puzzles and Code Golf

Ktojtassitj Kubbpey atp Yope Jopt
<===========>
This text has a
newline in it

Pkiy pekp kay a
tejpite it ip
<===========>
Corpus language best language

Yotkuy patjuaje teyp patjuaje
<===========>
Strip the flesh! Salt the wounds!

Yptik pke tpeyk! Yapp pke joutpy!
<===========>
"Install Warframe" they said, "It'll be fun" they said

"Itypapp Jatttase" pkey yaip, "Ip'pp te tut" pkey yaip
<===========>
What the **** did you just ****ing say about me, you little *****?
I'll have you know I graduated top of my class in the Navy Seals,
and I've been involved in numerous secret raids on Al-Quaeda,
and I have over 300 confirmed kills.

Jkap pke **** pip you tuyp ****itj yay atoup se, you pipppe *****?
I'pp kate you ktoj I jtapuapep pok ot sy ypayy it pke Taty Yeapy,
atp I'te teet ittoptep it tusetouy yeytep taipy ot Ap-Ruaepa,
atp I kate otet 300 yottitsep kippy.
```

#### The Bonus

If you also include an audio recording (or video with audio) of you pronouncing each of the testcase's Corpus translations, you may multiply your bytecount by `1` as a reward.

Comment: @Shaggy Sure, shoulda thought of that

Comment: @RobertS. it also provides no bonus to your score (`x * 1 == x`). It's a tongue-in-cheek poke at the unpronouncability of many of the translations

Comment: Can output be an array of characters?

Comment: @Skidsdev The "translations" are pronounceable; either as a recorded human voice or programmatically using machine learning and/or text-to-speech technologies.

Comment: @ngn oops my bad, copied from reddit :P

Comment: I showed this to a friend and now he's translating his texts. It's really hard to translate back because it's lossy (not one-to-one).

Help.

Comment: And so was born the Finnish language!

Answer (score 8):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, 46

```bash
tr b-zB-Z ${a=typetjkitkpstokrtyputjkyb}${a^^}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDBahtBDIbv8xSyySnYIZBzKG0OiS8hwQHTHgJaj9Y7We1omdGssy6BvkZfry/iau1SMrd/PumX9FeYm@NRE1TLw7flD7j4ibc69qRvbdC2zyptMl1Mj9WH0dfXj@PxgZhlARtJ7GfuO2X3Qlm3uCb3lGSXsOtC3MFTORyYMmD0cCee4F64di9NyKD0rtCgMRdpzyEShAhB3Z2kvmRgjLuCO4LKjP8rt9YUetCGoDbjZgZrZD3pvZTo88zNVzErMsMGU22L0HzCI2QMfgHzlf759dtoZQ4lfmJu0@DZ6dIe@OBhlAJvxcZPP9M9GUfASopCR4sT5qDK55bLL2519m5woBNto@xhBZaHL6jkQaUHqaEbYcuY83TyNPERhxHWhJwXbspq8hmm08kiiYPwYL1WG0tHSSydTNtECsn2ziARvvLyuSB5/Nd/XkEGSnBzfQ1biXVInZm0gTlf/QU)

Answer (score 4):

## T-SQL, 107 Bytes

```sql
SELECT TRANSLATE(v,'bcdfghjlmnpqrstvwxzBCDFGHJLMNPQRSTVWXZ',
                   'typtjktpstkrtyptjkbTYPTJKTPSTKRTYPTJKB')FROM t
```

Line break and indent are for readability only.

Uses the SQL 2017 function [`TRANSLATE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for character replacement.

Unfortunately had to put (almost) the entire alphabet in there *twice* to maintain casing. There are probably better ways, maybe something that handles the **t**'s as a group, but this worked for me.

Input is via a pre-existing table **t** with varchar column **v**, [per our IO rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

In this case the table must be created using a *case-sensitive collation*, either by running on a case-sensitive server, or by using the `COLLATE` keyword (not counted toward character total):

```sql
CREATE TABLE t(v varchar(999) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 24 bytes

```
ži.•ÜÁ©;«ìñä°ÔG·ÖYΘ•Du«‡
```

Explanation:

```
                       ‡   transliterate
ži                         a-zA-Z with
  .•ÜÁ©;«ìñä°ÔG·ÖYΘ•       atypetjkitkpstokrtyputjkyb
                    Du«    concatenated with itself, uppercased
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUMAvP9vc2FiaWX//8W@aS7igKLDnMOBwqk7wqvDrMOxw6TCsMOUR8K3w5ZZzpjigKJEdcKr4oCh//9IZWxsbywgV29ybGQh)

Comment: Minor [24 bytes alternative](https://tio.run/##AUEAvv9vc2FiaWX//8W@UC7igKI6w7N8INC9XcqSw5c64oKDw7DGkuKAouKAmkR1w7hKYOKAof//SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ) by transliterating just the consonants.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 42 bytes

```
≔”$⌊∧Ｔ-¶I^F⁷ü@n⁹γ›7η”η⭆θ⎇№β↧ι§⎇№βι↧ηη⌕β↧ιι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY1NDsIgGET3PQV2xZfgCbpCo7FWI7EY0yUCaUkIKMW/0yPdmXQ1eZmXGTmIIL2wKdFxNL3DJeUd2/B9U/OGtfzUnDNfMnerkqABqoIF4yJuY47@KO74QRDXwYnwxWv/zNWNoIN/6yDFqLEBIIjG2in9wTPPwL87wPRA0NY4NVuByQaoUtppaz1BVx@sWhRp@bI/) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔                       Assign
 ”$⌊∧Ｔ-¶I^F⁷ü@n⁹γ›7η”  Compressed string `ATYPETJKITKPSTOKRTYPUTJKYB` 
                     η  To variable

 θ                      Input string
⭆                       Map over characters and join
  ⎇                     If
    β                   Lowercase alphabet
   №                    Contains
      ι                 Current character
     ↧                  Lowercased
                        (Then)
        ⎇               If
          β             Lowercase alphabet
         №              Contains
           ι            Current character
                        (Then)
             η          Variable
            ↧           Lowercased
                        (Else)
              η         Variable
       §                Indexed by
               ⌕        Index of
                  ι     Current character
                 ↧      Lowercased
                β       In lowercase alphabet
                        (Else)
                   ι    Current character
                        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 100 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/[a-z]/gi,c=>(C='_atypetjkitkpstokrtyputjkyb'[Buffer(c)[0]&31],c>{}?C:C.toUpperCase()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZPBbhMxEIbvPMW0B5JUSVrUG1JSlRwgHFAhRVXVVGiyO5s469iWPd7iVki8Bq/Hi4RxliJAu7fxzPzzz2fvFhsMhVeOR8aWtK8m@zCZhrEnp7Gg/ukdjh7vT9dqWEym/dmk9wU5OeJtrbh2gW3tJY4Sp1Xv7k2sKvL9YnB3dv/y/NX9sJg@fbuYvZ6N2X52jvwMA/UHg8G@sCZYTWNt1/2q33tHWtsh3Fivy6PeYPDiv/wthY7Tawpc4II6Ulferj3udsqs4So@PmoKgKaEmSwJb62uuuQ2KgDTV4YNSvXSGHrQyhAoA4o7GmbWuxhAo1lHXBOsxM@fqKN@wQIaeENQiZ/NESxQ8yF@sNGUoWvz47kJjFrDDfpKNqLj3JAgoCqHcDznn99/SHYlmtH8leuQutlgO@1EPihVCclG2EYxnU8yqoAJcGUjw46Gh7RWzLptOblYmnk7boMNHdK1sQ8wB2FdRmQqga0DW8EuQaExhMwuj/yATYIFoQ7DpckXkYWajIwErmmsbqRZik3ckbdCNVDhicHLLgGsgUs9@hiRSnwWaE3Yhjycn52BLFspvxOVWmkdxh0A3tfowNW/ATi5i7wCx@RaALyFlAGwjU7mtwCkTF7uPwCcg1qWbQGw3YqXLaOL6Ej0bQ2WISRIDlOSl3MYeS3/DdwSupT9szsAEA0mWVIYW8fSLMUcA4kBaaeUjxiVS1nx0o0@CQCHzwKtCcsikAEky6w4SEstllMGsP8F)

```javascript
s =>                                  // s = input string
  s.replace(                          // replace in s ...
    /[a-z]/gi,                        // ... all letters, no matter the case
    c => (                            // for each letter c:
      C =                             //   pick a replacement letter C
        '_atypetjkitkpstokrtyputjkyb' //   from a 1-indexed lookup string
        [Buffer(c)[0] & 31],          //   using the 5 lowest bits of the ASCII code of c
      c > {} ?                        //   if the original letter was in lower case:
        C                             //     use the replacement letter as-is
      :                               //   else:
        C.toUpperCase()               //     convert it to upper case
    )                                 // 
  )                                   // end of replace()
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 79 bytes

```r
function(x)chartr("b-zB-Z",paste0(y<-"typetjkitkpstokrtyputjkyb",toupper(y)),x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVBBbtswELzrFRtdJAVSYaDXAEWbQ@NLkMIFjBa5rMSVxYjiCuRStnzqN/q9fsQl7aAoL@RydmZnx136h@bSB9uJZlueqm5AJ67M2@b8pfmZ1zN6oU25PjS5rDPJ26hlnL3w6GIdYr22eS0c5plcuVZVfaouPbtSQFvoyqx4ImO4hj07o@6KOit@kE/Xd/LS4Y7S@8XxweE0aXuAl3A@G/KAVsEjK4KvbPorYdAehE4CA0Y4s3Q02lKaoyU1PLKbgweD9hDwQNDGCf@q1LATp2eQgaCPE4Y72KGRa33kYJW/2su31gsaA3t0fTRFeepYwaNWNeRb@fPrd0TbKBLsf1ji7ge86d3HA0orWDnAW4g@0k9az@MK2HIQmKi@wkaLmBvl/lO2vckPuNAVHS0fYQsxHhVQSIHwDNzDtEJn0Pu0fpr4jMsKO0Lj6yxFl3SWlAHFeOzCZonc2GvDRI5jTJ46RwIuWvfAFj6b5ltAUvjOv1nghRx83GygY9trN0WRURvjPxRZVXUoZV9KVRev9tUW1eUv)

Only 3 bytes shorter than literally typing both lower- and uppercase replacement strings together...

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 79 bytes

```r
function(x,`[`=chartr)"B-Z"[toupper(y),"b-z"[y<-"typetjkitkpstokrtyputjkyb",x]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDBjtMwEL3nK2ZzSbJK0EpcFyHYA/SCFhWpgu5KO0kmjTeOJ7LHadMTv8Hv8SPFThHCF3v85r158@ylu68unTeNKDb5qXzZv7xrerRii/Rj9SPdC/tpIpsvRZnW1TndL/dVKstE8jooGSYnPNhQ@1AvdVqenp8vHdtcQBlo8iT7TFpzCTu2ur3JyiT7Ti5e38hJg1uK70fLB4vjqMwBHv35rMkBmhYeuCX4xLpbCb1yIHQS6DHAiaGjVobiHCWx4YHt5B1oNAePB4I6TPhXxYatWDWB9ARdmNDfwBa1rPWRvWndai/dGCeoNezQdsEUpbFjAYeqLSHdyO@fvwJaBxFv/sMid9fjVe82HGhVCwt7ePXBR/yJ6zlcAGv2AiOVK6yViL5Sbt8nm6t8jzOt6GD4CBsI8bQehVoQnoA7GBdoNDoX148Tv@C8wJZQuzKJ0UWdOWZAIR4zs54DN/QaP5LlEJOjxpKADdYdsIEPuvrqkVr8y79a4JksvL27g4ZNp@wYRAaltXuTJUXRoORdLkWZPZknkxWXPw)

Fancier code, same byte count.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 54 bytes

```perl
eval"y/B-Zb-z/".uc($a=typetjkitkpstokrtyputjkyb)."$a/"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@1LDFHqVLfSTcqSbdKX0mvNFlDJdG2pLIgtSQrO7Mku6C4JD@7CMgvBfIrkzT1lFQS9ZX@//dIzcnJ11EIzy/KSVH8l19QkpmfV/xftwAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>151</s> 83 bytes

```cs
n=>n.Select(a=>char.IsLetter(a)?(char)(" ATYPETJKITKPSTOKRTYPUTJKYB"[a%32]|a&32):a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVDNTsJAEL77FEMTzTbBHuCmUKMEFSGR2BpCrIehHegmyyzZ3UYwHnwNX88Xwa0aNenFPe33M99@s7k9zq3cX1ac9ybSul5eoonboyFXazK4UPTFxNv@nvsxRwkpyp3Aflzz0chOyDkyAsMzUTOhCOA8nU@H6c14lI6nSXo7vvP43uP5RfCAh93O4wsedTvhCYb704OBZqsVRTMjHU0kk7DOSF5FXsjRia0Irkkp3YaZNqpoBVGqB/6hc2NwJ0KP6t4irG/fXBj@K3aOu4x7/d8TZ5ySdTkm1BCmRq8Mrtc@AqbV87MiC8gFDHRBcKXVshlVSguOtg5K9N6MmZ6ULwKSQbqGfaDNprKgkFcVrggWvskPargTv8wGXEmw9E3KFiSo3Cd@0hUXttWYyIIRW4dKwQzN0q9CWVAP7MCiLNrgdff@@ub1hQ@t@K/6vz/ffwA)

Saved a whopping 68 bytes thanks to Pietu1998!

Comment: You can get this down to [83 bytes](https://tio.run/##jVDNTsJAEL77FEMTzTbBHuCmUKMEFSGR2BpCrIehHegmyyzZ3UYwHnwNX88Xwa0aNenFPe33M99@s7k9zq3cX1ac9ybSul5eoonboyFXazK4UPTFxNv@nvsxRwkpyp3Aflzz0chOyDkyAsMzUTOhCOA8nU@H6c14lI6nSXo7vvP43uP5RfCAh93O4wsedTvhCYb704OBZqsVRTMjHU0kk7DOSF5FXsjRia0Irkkp3YaZNqpoBVGqB/6hc2NwJ0KP6t4irG/fXBj@K3aOu4x7/d8TZ5ySdTkm1BCmRq8Mrtc@AqbV87MiC8gFDHRBcKXVshlVSguOtg5K9N6MmZ6ULwKSQbqGfaDNprKgkFcVrggWvskPargTv8wGXEmw9E3KFiSo3Cd@0hUXttWYyIIRW4dKwQzN0q9CWVAP7MCiLNrgdff@@ub1hQ@t@K/6vz/ffwA) by removing the range, combining the `Select`s and using bitwise operators for casing.

Comment: Thanks! Nice trick with the bit wise operators!

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 55 bytes

```ruby
$_.tr!"b-zB-Z",(x="typetjkitkpstokrtyputjkyb")+x.upcase
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDBbtswDIbvegrG6GHrnKDAzsOw9bDlMrRIgWC7DLRFx6pp0ZAoJ85pr7HX24PMk5OhqG6/fvIj@YdUTfN883OjYVVU6/Pn9Y@ifHP6UOg0kD53TrshqnQh65T1VBVv3502aagx0jx/JWYpYS@B7cp8p2ieKGqNOzIPQQ4B@975Azyk85kpAnoL92IJvgg35ql1EZROCi1mz3g6svMEzoNTcy9hSBEY/SHhgaDK4BdldhrcANoSNBncrmCHrBd9lORtXJli66MiM@wxNHkRKhZ7gojOllBs9c@v39mtMiH5V57Zt3gl3eYH1lmYJMFzyuOXn@WeiBNgJUmhp/Jis1Pla8vtR7O9slsc6eJ2Xo6whZyHTahkQWUAaaCfoGaMcTl5mfgNxwl2hBxLs2S1cMbldMqR@FF4zL251qeeguR0ItWBFELeO4J4@MTrx4Rk8X//dQUZKcD7uzuoxTcu9BnSOea4@SuDOvFxXg//AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>78</strike> 61 bytes

-17 bytes thanks to FrownyFrog!

```
rplc(u:,98 66+/i.25);"0(,toupper)@'typetjkitkpstokrtyputjkyb'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcoxCsIwGMXxvad4ZonFUougaEUQXPQEzql@0drYhOTL0EHwGl7Pi9RO6vh7/3frddjkKFCi6L0zp3Ess9USi8VkWuezeboWxThjG50jn24ld4741tTcuMC28YPj4K6SfZqIHFJvcokMjxI6JAmdrhYack/GWBytN@eR/K47610MMKq9RHUhVBT4q99NHNrAyhgcldde3UmAr9QhqPqcQRz4/XwNtSLo2P412X8A)

Comment: [61](https://tio.run/##TcoxCsIwGMXxvad4ZonFUougaEUQXPQEzql@0drYhOTL0EHwGl7Pi9RO6vh7/3frddjkKFCi6L0zp3Ess9USi8VkWuezeboWxThjG50jn24ld4741tTcuMC28YPj4K6SfZqIHFJvcokMjxI6JAmdrhYack/GWBytN@eR/K47610MMKq9RHUhVBT4q99NHNrAyhgcldde3UmAr9QhqPqcQRz4/XwNtSLo2P412X8A)

Comment: @FrownyFrog Thanks! In my J804 I can't use constants at the right-hand side. I need to upgrade :)
My solution is ugly nevertheless....

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <s>87</s> <s>63</s> <s>61</s> <s>60</s> 59 bytes

```
f:{`c$x-a-@[!128;98+!25;:;0+"typetjkitkpstokrtyputjkyb"]a:_x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVPRblMxDH3nK9wrpG2wwgAhjfYB0B6gm4QGmzRV28TcXrdNkybWjdM1Q/Drw7l3mjpB3mzHx/Y5tu37ub@/nw1@3Uyfb/rY/3TZe/P2cPjh8GXv7fvhYHjwspLMJEtrxHKUYBu1k9p5Ul3j4Ofm970Mfj2/zH@awQw2w5tgh7s3MzRuuBnmYbN3/fuZXFZfybmwDxehcXWvegZQnRCzeo6DMPeq6/JpTLENjSl3jnOKMsUzar2nlDnjmLrQaRPmDa5Wxs/hNN3dOYqAvoajUBN8CW7WFZGwFIzRyBJO0mTClAGFYRyYtDRLB3blq9e71fnCRBDaCCxQwQpA9ypPt854AuPBSLVXkLuUU2syMFkGi/lJitCSjWiKgOFqry1zFBpOERz6ecI5wUTHe7S6yYPYpIgoy4RL0m4yP1pdr2fSGAZZEMx05kUPztBJa9@G5OvYsTtmMRbYKoTObHswRubWXoYknB8Yv6pGPgo6BxfYzJRPuqoKVoaIpt4HjcuORidaLfntWFulhDMX5GMUUaJLuhbJkNFwm847GlUeJMl2bJv3iwV2A7zQB7WpIYcEy6TkFE9ROBZ2J9o5rGi/DTsj4rqUFx@3eB@Vdhe4pvaX9eEWRqCbUicUqkECQ5jBKsPU6V4URUvlb7jOcEbo4v4WVtmn0c66CEWqvF8Ht1YMzfFpRU1QLSNNGxJolJEIwcNn1/@ekGr8B6drKqypgXcHBzANfmaalcJZ41x8tb1VxxY7rVpCWOUus0jSXWgJ0WXOhRAJibWDjhD9xvxfQrhspzwQogehvehRcEImLRMsBIGosjDmXPa1VD5HyTAm5PxkED2d0U5Rk3RoVUAvSDE0R1IkbUdRKBeXqMa5AH/m/g8lhPEfnK6pIIpUCMlBxEjUXKuTZCXk@v4v)

`{` `}` function with argument `x`

`_` to lowercase

`a:` assign to `a`

`!128` the list `0 1 2 ... 127`

`@[!128;` *indices* `;:;` *values* `]` amend it by replacing the elements at *indices* with the given *values*

`98+!25` the list `98 99 100 ... 122` which are the ascii codes for `"bcd`...`z"`

juxtaposition is indexing, so we use `a` (implicitly converted to integers) as indices in the amended list

`x-a-` subtract from `a`, then subtract form `x`; this restores upper/lowercase as in the original string

`` `c$ `` convert to characters

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 59 bytes

```
[a-z]
 $&
T`l`L
T`L`ATYP\ETJKITKPST\OKRTYPUTJKYB
T`L `l_` .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDLbhNBELzvV3QsxCFyokhceShECBZHYNhFlpUgtu3p9Q7pnbHmsWZ94je4@Vv8KfyI02MjQNuHkaa6urq6HAVt8HC4w4vt12y/e/I0KyuubuW9ra7L@fT@Tfl@kpeTaVHef5x8FuSLAPPXibDfVfyt2u8uD4d3xGzHMLOO1Vn2/MW/epnNyQ@QknxYYkEDeOrsymHbarOCadxumTygUXBjFcFby/VQptEeAv0I0KAwM0Mb1oZAG9BhwL2xbh09MJpVxBXBQiz8/Q24RXB6DaEhqMVCcwYFcjj@NzYa5YcHjnLjAzLDDF0tB9AokXvwqNUYRnn4/fOXdBeiF81/vYHMrMHTlnMpUFpBbyN8j2I0ISkVjz3gwsYALY2PbdYh8Gnk/FWWnzY12NGx@2DsBnKQVFXEQAqCXYOtoe1hyeh9iipt/IBdDwUh@3GWEk86XQqJJErTWe5kVrgmtuSs5Ohp6SiAkys8WAPXfPEpIin8M3@yYDty8OzqCpbW1Nq1IvKgmf3lIw) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
[a-z]
 $&
```

Prefix a non-ASCII character to each letter. (I tried to use a non-breaking space but Firefox might have changed it back to a regular space after copying and pasting.)

```
T`l`L
```

Uppercase all of the letters.

```
T`L`ATYP\ETJKITKPST\OKRTYPUTJKYB
```

Convert the letters to Corpus.

```
T`L `l_` .
```

Lowercase the letters after the non-ASCII character and delete the non-ASCII character.

Naïve solution is 63 bytes:

```
T`lL`aty\petjkitk\pst\okrty\putjkybATYP\ETJKITKPST\OKRTYPUTJKYB
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBNj9NADL3nV3h7XBW0Elc@tKwQhCIoJKiqlMO6HaeZjTOOZjwp2RN/g7@3f6RMWgQovvm952f7eVLr8HQq7/nTPepY9aQPrdW26oNW0voJigkad7fldl29Kz@u8nK1Lsrqy@pbQr4nYPv2dPpAzLKEjXg2V9nLV//qdbalMENKCrrHgmbw2svBY9dZd4B1fHxkCoDOwJ0YgvfC9dymsQGUfig0mJSZoyNbR2AdWJ1p78T3MQCjO0Q8EOzSCX@7mbZQb3vQhqBOJzRXUCDruT9KdCbMH1zkLigywwZ9nR6gxSQeIaA1S1jk@vTzV2J3yS@6/7iZzabBy5brVGCsgVEiPMR06IRMqQQcAXcSFTpanmm2qnwZuX6T5ZdNDQ50ZlsnR8ghpWoiKhlQ6UFq6EbYM4YwRTVt/IzDCAUhh2U2JT75DFNIlKJ0g/CQZpPWxY68pBwD7T0p@PRFAHFwy8@@RiSDf@YvJ8hAHl7c3MBeXG19l0xayxye/wY) Link includes test cases.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 115 bytes

```python
lambda i:i.translate(''.join(a))
a=map(chr,range(256))
b='typetjkitkpstokrtyputjkyb'
a[66:91]=b.upper();a[98:123]=b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVJNb9pAEL37V0x8sUkpSoiKGlpaVTm0XKpUREJV6GHMjvHCetfanTV1/jwdQ5XkRvY28@bjzXvbdFw5Oz6Us9XBYF0oBD3VI/Zog0GmPMtGW6dtjoNBgrMam3xd@aHAG8rHHyaSLWYZdw3xdqd51wR2Oy9xlLgrsgQfJ5Pp7fWfWTGKTUM@H3zCx9uP0@vxjeQOjdeWoczTH2SMg6XzRl2kA3gH6cp@nr28LyubJs/VvymcL3qgwGtc0PnKe@82Huta2w3cx6cnQwHQKrhziuC7M@XZEVmWPVQ6ANNfhgqlPbG0N9oSaAuaBT/LYsFeN8AVQSkEqgtYoOFjvHfRqvAGXe6cb2IAI/ZE3BAUIsFzdP6IdG4DozGwRF@KIJT26zsIqNUQ0jmvMgELIRjtKyh7gzrLCk@3XMoDpRV0LsI2Cr8@0ysfsAMsXGSoaXiEjWY2p5bLr8n8uL3Clo7gzro9zEGMU1F@qgJ2DbgS6g7WBkPohe8X/sS2gwWhCcOkN1XGtL0yJL7Y1plWWqXUxpq8E/ECrT0xeDksgLPwzbz/FZEU/m8/MXAtebi5uoK1s6X2tQzZaWPCqHf68A8)

Adapted from @ElPedro's answer. This generates the replacement for every ascii character in the array `a` and then uses `str.translate`.

Can be brought to **113 bytes** if returning an array of chars is acceptable:

```python
lambda i:[a[ord(x)]for x in i]
a=map(chr,range(256))
b='typetjkitkpstokrtyputjkyb'
a[66:91]=b.upper();a[98:123]=b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVJNb9pAEL37V0x8sZ1SlBAVNbS0qnJouVSpiIQq4DBmx3hhvWPth8H583RtorRSL2Fvs2/e7Jv3tm5dyXp0Kqark8IqFwhyssQlG5Ees3XBBo4gNch1hNMK63RTmoFBvaV09GGcZVE@TVxbk9vtpdvX1vHehNqHus2TCJfj8eT@dj3Nh76uyaTZJ1zef5zcju7C3ak2UjtIkuGOpU6LNP5BSjEs2ChxFWcZvIN4pT9P/54vKx1H/9F@k72g@4ms2@CcLqA8Gt4arCqpt/Don58VWUAt4IEFwXdWxdtnJUnyVEoLjo4OSgxzIk0HJTX1PruAv13X3BlZgysJiiCpvII5KtfXB/Za2EtMfGBTewsqhOtxS5AHm16rC/aLZ9o6VAoWaIpgGsWdoBYsSjGAeOZWSQDzINnrf6DkEgcXJZ7XvA4HhBTQsoedD4q7my4miy1gzt5BRYMeVtI5daZcf41mvYwSG@rBveYDzCCkLDw6EuC4Bi6gamGj0NounO7Bn9i0MCdUdhB1PyCMaTqvKGSnG1ZNoIZW7SsyHOy0tDHkwIQNLbCGb@r9L48k8IV@VsANGbi7uYEN60KaKgzZS6XssP8Npz8)

Comment: Took some thinking at this time of night to work out how it was doing it. It's been a long day! Nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 29 bytes

```
“qḍỊYl4ḃ©ƭṄxḳ½Dy’ṃⱮØA,Øa¤⁺żẎy
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY69TsNAEIT7PMXWkUGRoEeRaNIgIQpEufFt4kvWd3A/BndBoUKCOkiUNBQgIZokQOMI3uP8IuZw2HJnvpmZEHPZNPXs8SIs78LH7Rnvh@W8ev55Caubq7B8r74Oy3r2EFbz@u11s@gnmwVWT/X1@vszrO8j25xm6MBlBN14IKSAUnuYeOvaj1RjsFgCDrV3kFPSyiyd4y3SPegMYgMzZFhQq06VvoQBjA0Kj44EOH0OegR5CSmjtSBV23iERQknhGyTDioBfzkxYkikoqXQXEQ2epXPyWhvwVJqyIFBKSxoBX3eOfZIAv/57QRdkIG9Xg9SrUbS5DFkKpnt7i8)

Comment: Only need to map consonants, so [`“ØṖ¦Mṗẏʋ@¥;}/’ṃⱮØCŒH¤⁺żẎy`](https://tio.run/##LY4xT8MwFIT3/oqbqwKVGBkAsdABJMTA/Bq/Nm4dG8V2UAakIkYkkBigSIzAiMSYiClVF/5F8keCSXnju/vubsZK5W3bLF5Xy7p4qj5O6uK5Lh9@7g6q973rnWbxUhe3zdfnanm0fjyu3pqbcv1dl/cBai9icnAxox8OQgrkxmPmres@Uk9hKQeNjXdIeNDJSjqnNkh/vzcKBUohpow7da7NFUaYpiQ8ORZw5hJmgiRHpMhaSN01nlKW45xJ2UGPtMBfTogYM@tgyYzKAhu82iecGm9hOUrZISUpLIzGodo688SC/vnNBJNxit3hEJHRE5kmIWQulbLbvw) saves 4. (Can't get rid of 'y' with `ØY` since it's on the right of the map)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 37 bytes

```
;®i`…ypetjkŠkp¡okrtyp©jkyb`pu)gCpu bZ
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=O65pYIV5cGV0amuKa3Chb2tydHlwqWpreWJgcHUpZ0NwdSBiWg==&input=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)

The above link includes most test cases, but I haven't been able to input the second to last one as a string because it contains both single and double quotes. [Here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=O65pYIV5cGV0amuKa3Chb2tydHlwqWpreWJgcHUpZ0NwdSBiWg==&input=WyciJywnSScsJ24nLCdzJywndCcsJ2EnLCdsJywnbCcsJyAnLCdXJywnYScsJ3InLCdmJywncicsJ2EnLCdtJywnZScsJyInLCcgJywndCcsJ2gnLCdlJywneScsJyAnLCdzJywnYScsJ2knLCdkJywnLCcsJyAnLCciJywnSScsJ3QnLCInIiwnbCcsJ2wnLCcgJywnYicsJ2UnLCcgJywnZicsJ3UnLCduJywnIicsJyAnLCd0JywnaCcsJ2UnLCd5JywnICcsJ3MnLCdhJywnaScsJ2QnXQotUA==) is that test case, input as an array of characters instead.

Explanation:

```
;                                        #Set C to the lowercase alphabet
 ®                                       #For each character Z of the input:
                                   bZ    # Find its index in:
                               C         #  The lowercase alphabet
                                pu       #  Plus the uppercase alphabet
                                         #  (-1 if it is not a letter)
                              g          # And get the character at that index in:
   `…ypetjkŠkp¡okrtyp©jkyb`              #  Get the lowercase Corpus alphabet
                           pu)           #  Plus the uppercase Corpus alphabet
  i                                      #  Add Z at the end (index -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>138</s> 132 bytes

```python
def f(i,a='bcdfghjlmnpqrstvwxz',b='typtjktpstkrtyptjkb'):a+=a.upper();b+=b.upper();return''.join((x,b[a.find(x)])[x in a]for x in i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVJNb9swDL3nV7C@OG68oNhu67Jh6GHLZeiQAsHQ9EBHdKxEpjyJcuL8@VR2hqy3lCdSjx@Pj2o6qSx/PJ0UlVCOdY6ztFirclNtTc3NX@el3R@OaV7MUuka2e6k8bJzZ79Is884meE0NA25cXZfTGbFJXAkwXGaTrdW83h8yItnnJaa1fiQvWTPB9AM@FJaB4Ors1PjNEukkfwkYywsrTPqJslgAsmKv8z@29cVJ6NL9h/y15OeyMsaF3Q989HZjcO61ryBx3A8GvKArODBKoIf1pRXW6Rp@lRpD0IHgQpj@YhpbzTTsKhE/CqLhTjdgFQEZSRQ3cACjQzx3gZW/h26PFjXBA8GeRNwQ1BECS7R9SWSOXtBY2CJroyCUNKP78CjVjkkc1mlESwiwcBvoPQd6iwrPO9yGw2UVtDZANsQ@fUvvfIeO8DCBoGa8gE2WsScS26/jebD9ApbGsAd2z3MIR5OBRRSILYBW0Ldwdqg973w/cBf2HawIDQ@H/VHjW3aXhmKd@HWmjaWxlQONTkbxfO0jv8YXFzMg2X4bj78DkgK/5WfGdiWHHy6u4O15VK7OjbZaWP8tL/06RU)

Actually shorter with a named function than with a lambda!

lambda version, **138** bytes

```python
lambda i,a='bcdfghjlmnpqrstvwxzBCDFGHJLMNPQRSTVWXZ',b='typtjktpstkrtyptjkbTYPTJKTPSTKRTYPTJKB':''.join((x,b[a.find(x)])[x in a]for x in i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVFNc9owEL3zKza@CFKXybS3TkmnodOEpMmQ2BOahhzWSMYCWXKllcH8eSqbTtob2dNKbz/ee1s1VBj9YZ@P5nuFZcYRZIwjli14vixWqtTVb@uo3mx3F@Nv3y@vrn/c3k3vH5L0cfbzF4uzEaOmotWaKkdre8iz9GmaXt@k0yS9eTjkF@wTY8OVkbrf38bZMw5zqXl/O3gZPG9BasCX3FjoUjnYV1ZqgrwfXQmlDMyMVfwkGsA7iOb68@hfnM911HutfhLueFEqHC0wEccrp9YsLZal1EuY@t1OCQeoOYwNF3BpVH50BGMsLaQDEluCAkN7T4uNklp0QingR1kkZGUFVAjIA4HiBBJU1L03xmvu3uDL2NjKO1Colx6XArJgwevruIhooh2hUjBDmwdDRNSub8Ch5DFEE5qzAGaBoNf/QewN7swKPGg5DQFccmiMh5UP/Nqf1nmHDWBmPEEp4g5WkkgdWk6/9Cbd9gJr0YFrbTYwgXA47pEEBzIVmBzKBhYKnWuNbxfeYd1AIlC5uNceNYypW2dEuIuujapDayjVvhTWBPOcWFhBYIMwB0bDV/X@3qPg@Lf9wMDUwsLHszNYGJ1LW4Yha6mUG7aX3v8B)

**<s>131</s> 125** if we are allowed to return an array of characters and have the `join` outside the function.

```python
def f(i,a='bcdfghjlmnpqrstvwxz',b='typtjktpstkrtyptjkb'):a+=a.upper();b+=b.upper();return[(x,b[a.find(x)])[x in a]for x in i]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVNNj9MwEL33V8zm4mQbqhXcgILQHqAXtKgrVajtYVJPGrfOOPgjbfrni5OiBYnLxqcZP7/xmzd20/nK8NvrVVIJZapynItiJ8t9ddA1N7@s8@3pfBF5MRe@a/zh6Bvnj/YWFyJ7j9M5zkLTkE2zD8V0XrwklnywvE7PebHGWalYpudsm63PoBhwWxoLQ6i218Yq9iDE7GAUp2WafCOtDayM1fIuyTKYQrLhj/O/69OGk8l/tJ/kRpx@Jud3uKQRlCdr9hbrWvEensLloskBsoRHIwm@Gl2@vpYQ4rlSDjydPVQY60yYTloxDab4iL9e19Jb1YCvCMooqbqDJWo/5CcTWLoxJj4a2wQHGnkfcE9QRJteshH9JQt2HrWGFdoymkZJL6gDh0rmkCz8RkSwiJID/wOJMQ6uKry1eR8XSCWhMwEOISrud/oxOewACxM81JQPsFbe6xvl/vNkMciosKUBPLI5wQLilGVATxK8acCUUHew0@hcP5z@wu/YdrAk1C6f9C8glml7ryjOjluj20iNRznUZE2009EufgiwsUMHhuGLfvMjIEn8Q78pMC1ZePfwADvDpbJ1LHJUWrvZ8BquvwE)

Comment: You can still use a lambda if you make `a` and `b` global variables

Comment: @BlackOwlKai - Thanks. Have been playing with that idea but it's getting late. Maybe tomorrow :)

Comment: Got it down to [120/113 characters](https://tio.run/##DchLCsMgFADAvadwp0IJxFJpLJ7EZvFsTGM@KtZAPL11ORNLXoLndVbvusNhJsBOEtKtwXkKOqSJXmycQ8IXdh47hkAdEOlnSbcE/mspfwjGkFEkl2jzurm8xV8OW2o@m4shCLQQcuhHZbozRpsoe4EenrLn93a1/gE) (TIO without the testcases, else the link would be too long for a comment)

Comment: Beats mine and different enough for you to post as your own answer. I'll upvote :)

Comment: Feel free to steal my test cases as well. They took longer to type in than the code...

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 100 bytes

**Code**

```php
<?=strtr($argv[0],($u=bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz).($f=strtoupper)($u),($v=typtjktkpstkrtyptjkyb).$f($v));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcuxDoIwFIXhnadoSAeaGOKOlcGBld04FKFFCvR6e6nCy2OjcTw53w897KcSeki4QhOuxxuTLK3RGVTT9JgNq5dtGzvP1Nyyi2s7VrlRp0VSnmMoPSFh9m8PGV9kc2@16Qc7TjM80VN4vddN5BnXX@0WgA5FlCLyIGkFGixZ8GTxN9ZG5FzHU4hi3z8)

**Explanation**

```php
# using the provided character mapping given on the question, as an array
strtr($argv[0],                                  # strtr for the string replacement
($u=bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz).($f=strtoupper)($u),  # Taking onthe the keys for the first string
($v=typtjktkpstkrtyptjkyb).$f($v));              # Using the values for second string
 # In both Strings appending the upper version of each string.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 35 Bytes

```
XQ.*m+r1dd[tG."byàHuH¯¹e?rJyfh
```

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=XQ.%2am%2Br1dd%5BtG.%22by%04%C3%A0Hu%05H%C2%AF%C2%B9e%3FrJyfh%22&input=%22Hello%2C+World%21%22&debug=0)

Could probably use Left map or something to get rid of the two d's, but I couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 211 Bytes

```
a->{String b="BCDFGHJLMNPQRSTVWXZbcdfghjlmnpqrstvwxz",c="TYPTJKTPSTKRTYPTJKBtyptjktpstkrtyptjkb";a.chars().map(x->{int z;return(z=b.indexOf(x))>-1?c.toCharArray()[z]:x;}).forEach(x->System.out.print((char)x));};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZHfb4IwEMef51/R8VQSIdnrCFum@2F0bk7IdDM@lFIUhMLakyGGf32sINnivfRyvX7ve59GJCdG5O/qOtt7cUgRjYmUaEpCjo49pCLkwERAKEPLrtJEnoY@4tgBEfINIrrV3lS99pBAQEktUYFsRIybY9fm2dpgeP/4NBo/T19mb3PHfV8sPz3qB5ttFCc8@xIS8u@i1PrU1tyPmTueuDPHncxP@QAOGUQ7yCTsxCn3NIuYdEuExLqZkAwXapyyjEpLMNgLjkvbM0Pus@I1wIWu3xhXt9SEdKje3AlBDlhflevrwqp0M0jFA6HbRsM5SGCJme7BzJR3wLgZoisBq7JOW3bAumVbIInC1jFZrRERG6krZhesYHQPzGUSlM0zVEo8J8DOVM7b27Z/8KgwOdZGLI7TPlqkIvYvtT/Jqq7rnzSDMOWyNhipm3/8BQ)

Comment: [191 bytes](https://tio.run/##VZFfT4MwFMWf3aeoPNHENT6L02T@WzancxA3XfbQQWEwKNhesGPhq4uFEc3uS29ub07P7zSiBe1H3q7O8k0cusiNqZRoSkOODj2kK@TAhE9dhpbdpKkiDT3ETRtEyANEsdXeVL32kEBBSy2RQoOa9m8OlLhbKqSJSUIzU@mJVkXlwBje3T8@jcbP05fZ29x23hfLz43r@cE2ihOefQkJxbcqDRJyj6lX31TYEgxywVF5fXmrrgznY@aMJ87MdibzYz@EfQbRDjIJO3HsNwYJGAz3wLSFVbm2Kkz8VDxQd9uYsfcSWELSHEimccA0G7dYYWxVVt0Addl0XC17ohPq8FdrREUgsY7njCnm5sAcJkG/dZKK1i4osBOV0/V27T9jpAg3jRGL4/QCLVIRe@fGn2RV1z9pBmHKZd1ntG5@7Bc "Java (JDK) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 34 chars

```
J."byàHuH¯¹e?rJyfh"XXztGJrtG1rJ1
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J.%22by%04%C3%A0Hu%05H%C2%AF%C2%B9e%3FrJyfh%22XXztGJrtG1rJ1&input=Hello+World%21&test_suite_input=Yey%0A%3C%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3E%0ATestcaSe%0A%0APeypyaYe%0A%3C%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3E%0AProgramming+Puzzles+and+Code+Golf%0A%0AKtojtassitj+Kubbpey+atp+Yope+Jopt%0A%3C%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3E%0AThis+text+has+a%0Anewline+in+it%0A%0APkiy+pekp+kay+a%0Atejpite+it+ip%0A%3C%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3E%0ACorpus+language+best+language%0A%0AYotkuy+patjuaje+teyp+patjuaje%0A%3C%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3E%0AStrip+the+flesh%21+Salt+the+wounds%21%0A%0AYptik+pke+tpeyk%21+Yapp+pke+joutpy%21%0A%3C%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3E%0A%22Install+Warframe%22+they+said%2C+%22It%27ll+be+fun%22+they+said%0A%0A%22Itypapp+Jatttase%22+pkey+yaip%2C+%22Ip%27pp+te+tut%22+pkey+yaip%0A%3C%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3E%0AWhat+the+%2a%2a%2a%2a+did+you+just+%2a%2a%2a%2aing+say+about+me%2C+you+little+%2a%2a%2a%2a%2a%3F%0AI%27ll+have+you+know+I+graduated+top+of+my+class+in+the+Navy+Seals%2C%0Aand+I%27ve+been+involved+in+numerous+secret+raids+on+Al-Quaeda%2C%0Aand+I+have+over+300+confirmed+kills.%0A%0AJkap+pke+%2a%2a%2a%2a+pip+you+tuyp+%2a%2a%2a%2aitj+yay+atoup+se%2C+you+pipppe+%2a%2a%2a%2a%2a%3F%0AI%27pp+kate+you+ktoj+I+jtapuapep+pok+ot+sy+ypayy+it+pke+Taty+Yeapy%2C%0Aatp+I%27te+teet+ittoptep+it+tusetouy+yeytep+taipy+ot+Ap-Ruaepa%2C%0Aatp+I+kate+otet+300+yottitsep+kippy.&debug=0&input_size=20)

The string is a compressed version of *"typetjkitkpstokrtyputjkyb"*. For some reason I cannot get Pyth to compress *"atypetjkitkpstokrtyputjkyb"* with the function

```
+++\.N++hSzeSzCi-RChSzCMz-hCeSzChSzN
```

even though it would probably save a byte or two as the two t's could be eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 114 bytes

```
proc C s {string map [split {btcydpftgjhkjtlpmsntpkqrrtsytpvtwjxkzbBTCYDPFTGJHKJTLPMSNTPKQRRTSYTPVTWJXKZB} ""] $s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVHRbtswDHz3V7DGgAJFNhTYBwxrhrVJtsKtjWVZ0QfZpmMnsqSJlFMnyLdnVDIM04Mg6cjj3YkrfTo5byuYAsGB2HdmDb1y8EJOdwyHkquxdg2vN@12w9r1ZNhtf3vPNLIbeLd52@7Lu2K6@pJ9Le7nD4t58S37nj8W2eLp@bnIV0X2o1jOfy5@3R0hTV/hHR1POo6QgUn6gFrbCSyt1/VVmqQrJNkLJK5UjnLMvF171fdRWBb2e40EytQwtTXCvdVNLG87AsY3hlYJmhjc6c4gdAY6FnxqvQsEWpl1UGuEUuj/3QTPxbcDbhEaoW@vIFeaz/edDaYmEXZIZ4ZYaQ1L5RsRhGksGIFUV08gnfG1YKUwBPMfckzSZasuXDeyoO5qGG2ATRAJ8SX6IjWCKm1g6HFyhiV71peWm0/JLHK3asAztjV2BzOQVOqgGGtg68A20I9QaUUUbcd5j2oYIUelaZLExGbXQ7SOEooZrB6kUypN6NFbSYew8sjgRTWBNfBZv38KCmv1t/siwA7o4ePtLVTWNJ3vhWTbaU0f0uQIBxeY4GUqf/x6PP0B)

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 153 bytes

```lua
t="atypetjkitkpstokrtyputjkyb"for c in(...):gmatch"."do i=c:lower():byte()-96n=t:sub(i,i)io.write((i<0or i>26)and c or(c==c:upper()and n:upper()or n))end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU9Nb4MwDL33V1hcClWLqk2qNDQ27djLpGmHHaoeDDElJcQocaj49Sylm2/P78s2AWfDqLw4bS@n0yxlgjINJNdOSzd44c5FHCKeqqRhBzVom@Z5nhWXHqVukzxRDLqsC8M3cmlWVJNQmu1eDraUwocq1Vudac5vTkci1a/7GKPfng4ZWhXz2KV1Gf1hGO7@@9L@g6i0WUZWzefz0jrPPy0KSEuwiQNKK5g4wDV4WTbxD/A4AVYcBHraLrTRIuZh2byvjmtjoMWRFq6zfIMjXByqgEIKhAfgBvoJaoPex4eXvk8cJ/gmNH67uh95XMeAishGwchmjM6otKEnx8GDp9qRgEOtPLCFD7P7CkgK/9yPA3gkB8/7PdRsG@36GNJpY3z@Cw)